# Multiple Queries: Multi Variables or One Query

Tags: php, mysql

I had a lot of help in writing all of this in php (mainly the first long query).

```
// Query the database for data
$query = "SELECT cards.card_id, concat(title, \" By Amy\") AS TitleConcat, 
    description, meta_description, 
    seo_keywords,concat(\"http://www.amyadele.com/attachments//cards/\",cards.card_id,\"/\",card_image) AS ImageConcat,price 
FROM cards, card_cheapest 
WHERE cards.card_id = card_cheapest.card_id 
ORDER BY card_id";


$result = mysql_query($query);


// Open file for writing
$myFile = "googleproducts.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

// Loop through returned data and write (append) directly to file
fprintf($fh, "%-25s %-200s  %-800s   %-200s %-800s %-800s\n", "id", "label","description","price","image","seo keywords");
fprintf($fh, "\n");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 fprintf($fh, "%-25s  %-200s  %-800s  %-200s %-800s %-800s\n", $row['card_id'], $row['TitleConcat'], $row['description'],$row['price'],$row['ImageConcat'], $row['seo_keywords']);
}

// Close out the file
fclose($fh);

echo "The file has been written sucessfully to googleproducts.txt. It will run again tomorrow at 12:00pm."
?>
```

However, over the last couple of days I have written a couple other queries which leads me to my question. Would it be easier to somehow stick this other queries into the first "select", or would it be easier to set up multiple queries and then just insert that into the rows as well (I dont even know if that is even possible).

Query: Selecting the Min Price

```
select card_id, min(card_price) from card_lookup_values where card_price > 0 group by card_id;
```

Query: Creating URL Structure

```
SELECT CONCAT('http://amyadele.com/', cards.title, '/', categories.seoname, '/', cards.seoname),cards.card_id
FROM cards
LEFT JOIN card_categories
  ON card_categories.card_id = cards.card_id
LEFT JOIN categories
  ON card_categories.category_id = categories.category_id ORDER by card_id;
```

I guess my question is is it best to set up my queries (which I already know work) into multiple variables and then somehow push that into the table format I have set up, or to somehow format all of these queries into one long query?

I recently just wrote

```
 SELECT 
            replace(lower(concat( 'http://www.amyadele.com/', pcat.seoname,'/',cat.seoname, '/', cards.seoname, '.htm' )),' ','+') AS link,
            concat(pcat.name,'>',cat.name) as category,
            replace(lower(concat( 'http://www.amyadele.com/', cat.seoname, '/', cards.seoname, '.htm' )),' ','+') AS add_to_cart_link          
          FROM cards 
          INNER JOIN card_categories cc ON cards.card_id = cc.card_id AND cards.card_live = 'y' AND cards.active = 'y' AND cc.active = 'Y'
          INNER JOIN categories cat ON cat.category_id = cc.category_id AND cat.active = 'Y'
          INNER JOIN categories pcat ON cat.parent_category_id = pcat.category_id
          INNER JOIN card_lookup_values clv on clv.card_id=cards.card_id and clv.lookup_detail_id
          WHERE cat.parent_category_id <>0
          ORDER BY cc.card_id
```

However, I am really confused on how to even add this now

Comment: `%-800s` what's an odd string formatting? o_O And.... what are the other queries? You've got only one... No? Only I who don't understan the question a bit less than completely?

Comment: My bad, I will tweak the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adding" the query.

Comment: Sorry. "Combining" the two is what I really meant. I have more of an understanding on how you did the last one. Though I just keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'joins' to aggregate all of this information into a single response from the DB. I don't know your exact schema, so some of this is just a guess, but here is how I would start.

```
SELECT 
  cards.card_id, 
  concat(cards.title, ' By Amy') AS TitleConcat, 
  cards.description, 
  cards.meta_description,
  cards.seo_keywords,
  concat('http://www.amyadele.com/attachments//cards/',cards.card_id,'/',cards.card_image) AS ImageConcat,
  card_cheapest.price,
  card_import.author,
  min(card_lookup_values.card_price)
FROM
  cards
  join card_cheapest on cards.card_id = card_cheapest.card_id
  left join card_import on card_import.card_id = cards.card_id
  join card_lookup_values on card_lookup_values.card_id = cards.card_id
WHERE card_lookup_values.card_price > 0
GROUP BY
  cards.card_id
ORDER BY
  cards.card_id
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for the Help. I was just wondering (as your response eems like the direction I should probably head), but when I run the query I do recieve an error of " Title in field list is ambiguous". What does that that even mean?

Comment: Louis- That means that SQL can't figure out which table the 'title' belongs to in the third line. I'll edit my answer to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks again tom. It works great. I see now how you are "linking" things. It seems so simple. One quick question for you. I figured out how to add to the query, but I have a new peice I wrote and I am confused of how to add it due to so many joins. I posted it about in my "question".